# How does this method work

Tags: java

So i got `Graph.java` file and there is a method (there is more stuff in there):

```
public Graph(double y, int gr, String title, double vidurkis, double trend) {
   grooms = gr;
}
```

And this Graph method is no more mentioned in this Graph.java file. Now after grooms variable becomes `= gr = 30`. And `30` never mentioned in this `Graph.java`. So i imagine this method is being called from other file, right?

Now there is BrideInSwing.java file and there is have also Graph method used:

```
if (which == 1){
   graphic = new Graph((Math.floor(((d_bride+d_groom) * 3 + divorce) * 10)) / 10, grooms, "Number of grooms: " + grooms + "; bride distribution: " + d_bride + "; grooms distribution: " + d_groom, pr_vidurkis, trend);               
} else {
   graphic = new Graph((Math.floor((d_bride + d_groom) * 3 * 10)) / 10, grooms, "Number of grooms: " + grooms + "; bride distribution: " + d_bride + "; grooms distribution: " + d_groom, pr_vidurkis, trend);
}
```

So from what i understand this calls Graph method with parameters corresponding in `Graph.java` file? If so, then why there is more parameters given here than in `Graph.java` file where it is only 5: `y`, `gr`, `title`, `vidurkis`, `trend`.

Or am I completely missing something here? Thanks.

Comment: You're going to have to post an example we can run - this is hard to debug with missing information.

Comment: But to offer a general overview - both of them seem to have 5 parameters.

Comment: There are 5 files in project total, so i am not gonna post everything here obv.^^

Comment: If you learn how to post a http://sscce.org/ then you'll find future questions much easier / faster to solve. It strengthens your own debugging skills, too.

Comment: A lot of work to do sscce, but gonna check this out :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

public methods, by definition, are intended to be called from the oustide of the class (they can be called from the inside also, but if that's the only goal, the method should be private).

This method, however, is not a method, but a constructor.

And it's invoked with 5 arguments:

1. `Math.floor(((d_bride+d_groom)*3+divorce)*10))/10`,
2. `grooms`,
3. `"Number of grooms: "+grooms+"; bride distribution: "+d_bride+"; grooms distribution: "+d_groom`,
4. `pr_vidurkis`,
5. `trend`

What's the most troubling from your code is that the constructor takes 5 arguments, but does nothing with 4 of them. EIther the arguments should be used, or they should be removed.

Comment: Okey guys I understood everything. My stupid error was i put argument only in 1 if and not in else, now it works.

Also JB Nizet, i just didn't post all the code, it uses every variable. And you well explained all 5 arguments, but i still don't undertand why << "Number of grooms: "+grooms+"; bride distribution: "+d_bride+"; grooms >> is only one argument.

Comment: It's a string, obtained by concatenating various static parts (between quotes) with variables values. `+` is the concatenation operator. Arguments are separated by a comma.

Comment: Interesting, gonna read about this more! thx :)

Answer (score 3):

Your analysis of the code is not too far off really.

Your graph method is a constructor, a method for creating new objects. I'd suggest reading up on object-oriented programming and doing a tutorial or two to get your feet under you.

I did some quick googling and found [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html), should be up your alley.

Comment: Thanks, so that variable gr got value 30 because it was called from other file with certain parameters? Now then the main question: why when i want to add extra parameter in boths sides i cannot. For example in the end of Graph method i add int bb, and some other parameter in other file accordingly? Oh and my first question, why number of parameters does not correspond in different files?

Comment: Post your new versions of both the constructor and the calling line, plus the error message. Edit your question to include them, don't post them in a comment here.

Answer (score 2):

It is not a method, it is a `constructor`. It creates a new Object of class `Graph` with the given initialization parameters (given in the second code).

You can have overloaded constructor, several constructor each taking different number/types of parameters. The compiler will select the constructor that meets the specified parameter list (or throw a compiler error if none is available).

All of the above works too for regular methods.

Comment: And sdasdadas is right, there are both 5 parameters so that is the constructor being called (didn't thought I had to double check your counting...)